# How to root the Galaxy Attain 4G (SCH-R920) on MetroPCS?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-attain

I have an [Galaxy Attain 4G (SCH-R920) on MetroPCS](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/cell-phones/SCH-R920DSAMTR) running the Android™ 2.3 (Gingerbread).

How can I root this phone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Rooting the Galaxy Attain 4G (SCH-R920) on MetroPCS

<sup>A step by step tutorial accredit to [Zhelezaka from http://forum.x-drivers.com/](http://forum.x-drivers.com/index.php?showtopic=2295).</sup>

---

### Requirements:

**Necessary Files:** <sup>all files hosted on my DropBox account!</sup>

- [Odin3 v1.85](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ebpndvtwm26ofvc/odin3_v1.85.zip);
- [Attain Rooted Update](https://www.dropbox.com/s/brnjan5oamtbcc6/Attain-Rooted-Update.tar);
- [Attain 4G PIT File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sdui9ona0d9y9kc/Attain_4G.zip);

**Setup:**

- A PC running the Windows Operating System; <sup>I've used Windows 7</sup>
- The cable to connect your Android device to the PC.

---

### Tutorial:

1. Download all files from the "Necessary Files List" to a folder on your desktop;
2. Extract *odin3_v1.85.zip* to a folder on your desktop;
3. Locate and open the Odin 1.85.exe to open up Odin3;

   If the User Account Control (UAC) pops up, accept the execution of the file.

   [image: Odin Startup screen]
4. Click on the PDA button.
   Navigate to the location where you downloaded the *Attain-Rooted-Update.tar* file and select it.

   [image: PDA File Selection]
5. Click on the PIT button.
   Navigate to the location where you downloaded the *Attain-4G.pit* file and select it.

   Do not forget to extract the file first, since the application only works with the *Attain-4G.pit* file inside the ZIP you've downloaded.

   [image: PIT File Selection]
6. Make sure that repartition is unchecked.
   This is important as checking this will most definitely brick your device!

   Note that when you select the PIT file, it gets checked, you need to uncheck  it yourself.

   [image: Unchecked Re-Partition]
7. Power down your device;
8. With your device switched off, press and hold the <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd> buttons.
   Then press the <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> key to enter the Download Mode.
9. Connect your device to the Windows PC.
   You should see the ID:COM field light up yellow when you do this;

   [image: Odin Device Detected]

   If this does not happen, it means that you don’t have the necessary drivers installed.
   You can download Samsung Kies and install it to rectify this problem.

   - [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
   - [Samsung USB Driver](http://www.x-drivers.com/catalog/drivers/mobile_phones/companies/samsung/models/usb_driver/index.html)
10. Your Odin3 screen should now look like the picture posted below. Again, make sure that the Re-Partition tickbox is unchecked before you click Start!

    [image: Odin Final State]
11. Click on Start.

    **Note:** Once Odin3 says *"PASS"* and your device reboots, your Samsung Galaxy Attain 4G should be rooted!!
    If you are in doubt though, the usual way to confirm is to download [Root Checker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck&hl=en) from the Google Play Store or look for the Superuser app in the app drawer.

---

## Useful links:

- [Samsung Product Page](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/cell-phones/SCH-R920DSAMTR)
- [GSMArena Device Specifications](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_attain_4g-4431.php)

Comment: I can confirm that this works with Heimdall as well, however you have to unzip the .tar file and manually add the FACTORYFS partition file (factoryfs.rfs).