# How to root without a computer

Tags: rooting

I have a Samsung Galaxy Attain 4G and I was wondering about rooting my phone without using a computer. I just want to use my phone to root it. And [z4root](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=833953) doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Have you seen [this post](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/49925/how-to-root-the-galaxy-attain-4g-sch-r920-on-metropcs)? Looking at this, I'm inclined to say you need a computer.

Answer (score -2):

You positively need a computer. Rooting an Android phone means running an exploit, that the phone will not allow to run on itself. It can be run only on "Debug via USB" mode.

Comment: While rooting phones does sometimes require an exploit, this is not often the case. Additionally, I'm fairly certain that it is almost never done through USB debugging, but by flashing a SU binary or by flashing a rooted image. This can be done through recoveries or flashing tools.

Comment: Hey, dotVezz, how do you flash without a computer?

Comment: Here's the method I always use. 1: Grab the latest [SuperSU zip](http://download.chainfire.eu/365/SuperSU/UPDATE-SuperSU-v1.69.zip). 2: Flash it in [ClockWorkMod](http://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager) or [TWRP](http://teamw.in/project/twrp2). Alternatively, you can use a USB connection and Odin/Heimdall (for Samsung phones) or via `fastboot` (I think. Not 100% sure about the fastboot thing)

Comment: Rooting != exploit. Rooting is built into Android. Exploits must be used when the manufacturer or carrier prevent the natural rooting process.